# Windows Azure ignoring files with unknown extensions

Tags: azure

I have uploaded my website to windows azure. The website is working properly on the local server.

I am uploading images to the server.

**ISSUE:**

If the files had some weird names like  2013_6_5_15_12_33_144pwzve.lg2 
Windows azure shows 404 error
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

But works with this file name 2013_6_5_12_1_5_SampleStudent.png

I created some sample page to check if file is uploaded successfully it is.

All the files are on the server.
I checked using grid

grvNotSent.DataSource = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Test"));

Any idea?

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what is LG2? Have you [added a mime type for that file extension in the web.config](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent/mimemap)?

You can add the mime type mapping like this:

```
  <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
         <mimeMap fileExtension=".lg2" mimeType="whatever_this_type_is" />
      </staticContent>
   </system.webServer>
```

When IIS sees unknown mime type it ignores the request with 404.

Comment: thanks a lot. I dont know this. Actually i am creating the radom files name using Directory classes and they work on local but not on server. thanls +1 for good answer